# file output to specific directory using c++

Tags: visual-c++

so to give this context
I'm making a script generating the config files for some games I'm running.
I'm at this point just trying to get the script to generate the file and put it in the directory of said game. (this is still work in progress. and I don't have any way of getting user input. but first I need it to put it in the proper directory.)
in this example its minecraft.

but I can't find any posts on any forum or here on stackoverflow that works.
it might be because im missing the rest of the code as most people just give 3 lines of code.

point is I'm not experienced whit c++ as I have never used it.
so I'm hoping some one can help me fix it.

yes I added the full code I got so far as it probably is filled whit "shit" and a loot longer than what it needs to be so any help would be nice.

final note*
I'm using MS visual studio express 2013

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

// comment

/*
multi
line
comment
*/

//locked
// server ip : string
string ip = "127.0.0.1";
//server port : integer 1-65534
string port = "25565";
//world name : string
string world = "world";
//amount of allowed players : integer 0-2147483647
string mxpla = "20";
//view distance : integer 3-15
string viedis = "10";
//trexture pack :string
string texpack = "";


//user defined
// world gen setting : string (only used whit CUSTOMIZED leveltype)
string genset = "";
// allow flight : boolean true or false
string alfly = "true";
// level type : string DEFAULT, FLAT, LARGEBIOMES, AMPLIFIED, CUSTOMIZED --> same as DEFAULT unless generator settings is filled out
string levtype = "DEFAULT";
// level seed : string
string levseed = "";
// max build hight : integrer 0-256
string mxbh = "256";
//spawn npc : boolean true or false
string snpc = "true";
// whitelist : boolean true or false
string wlist = "false";
//spawn animals : boolean true or false
string sanimal = "true";
// hardcore mode : boolean true or false
string hc = "false";
//online mode : boolean true or false
string onmo = "true";
// pvp mode : boolean true or false
string pvp = "false";
//server difficulity : integer 0-3  0 peaceful - 3 hard
string diff = "1";
// game mode : integer 0-3  0 survival, 1 creative, 2 adventure and 3 spectator (dont use 3 on the server side)
string gamemo = "0";
// spawn mobs : boolean true or false
string smob = "true";
//generate structures : boolean ture or false
string genstru = "true";
// mesage of the day : string
string motd = "test";
int main() {

    ofstream outFile;
    // output file
    outFile.open("test.properties");
    // file generator
    outFile << "generator-settings=" << genset << endl
        << "level-name=" << world << endl
        << "allow-flight=" << alfly << endl
        << "server-port=" << port << endl
        << "level-type=" << levtype << endl
        << "level-seed=" << levseed << endl
        << "server-ip=" << ip << endl
        << "max-build-height=" << mxbh << endl
        << "spawn-npcs=" << snpc << endl
        << "white-list=" << wlist << endl
        << "spawn-animals=" << sanimal << endl
        << "hardcore=" << hc << endl
        << "texture-pack=" << texpack << endl
        << "online-mode=" << onmo << endl
        << "pvp=" << pvp << endl
        << "difficulty=" << diff << endl
        << "gamemode=" << gamemo << endl
        << "max-players=" << mxpla << endl
        << "spawn-monsters=" << smob << endl
        << "generate-structures=" << genstru << endl
        << "view-distance=" << viedis << endl
        << "motd=" << motd << endl;


    outFile.close();


    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ofstream`'s `open()` method takes a full path, so you can specify it like that:

```
outFile.open("c:\\games\\minecraft\\test.properties");
```

Comment: thanks.
i had the impression it would crate the directory if it didnt exist.
but turns out i needed to make c:\games\mincraft for it to work <,<
wish some one had pointed that out in the other posts earlier.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create output file at any folder than in VS you should change working directory. Go in `Solution properties` -> `Configuration properties` -> `Debugging` -> `Working directory` and change the value there to your preferred path. For example write there `C:\Games\minecraft`

Comment: This is a very bad idea; you should not rely on a current working directory. Besides, what if you need to create files in two (or more) different places?